# Using a .Net 4.5 library in a .Net 3.5 Project

Tags: asp.net

I started using the MailChimp.Net library in my .Net forms project which runs in the .Net 4.0 CLR.

I added the DLL and used it on various pages successfully. However, I need to move it into a library that currently targets the .NET 3.5 Framework. When I add the reference to MailChimp.net, I get errors saying it can't be loaded because it targets 4.5. When I change the target framework of my library project to 4.5, I get errors saying the site can no longer use it:

> The primary reference
> "\bin\debug\Library.dll"
> could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the
> .NET Framework assembly "System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher
> version "4.0.0.0" than the version "3.5.0.0" in the current target
> framework.

I feel like I'm missing something. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Focus on resolving this problem: `When I change the target framework of my library project to 4.5, I get errors saying the site can no longer use it.`  Please update ("Edit") your post with the exact error message.

Comment: don't try importing the code. Upgrade the site to 4.5 - fix the issues and errors. Then and only then do you want to start introduction of new code and libraries.

Comment: @paulsm4 - have done. Thanks.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal - This is a massive and legacy project. I cannot simply upgrade the site to 4.5.

Comment: You unfortantly don't have much choice. You want to use the newer .net libraries, then you need to upgrade the existing site. There is really not any other viable answer. It is not at all clear why a upgrade say from 3.5 to 4.5 would break much code - it simply should not. I upgraded some older .net sites and little if anything broke. But that kind of upgrade is required and there really is no other practical answer here.  Worse as time goes on, more and more libraries you would adopt are going to be off the table if you don't do this upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

1. You basically have two choices:

   - Find an old version of MailChimp.Net that works with your .Net 3.5 project
   - Upgrade your project to .Net 4.5 (or at least to .Net 4.0).
2. Upgrading your project *should* be fairly straightforward. As Albert D. Kallal said in his comments:

> An upgrade say from 3.5 to 4.5 simply should not break much code. I
> upgraded some older .net sites and little if anything broke. But that kind of
> upgrade is required and there really is no other practical answer here...

3. But the reality you're facing is:

   - Newer platforms tend to support backward compability with older assemblies,
     ... BUT ...
   - The reverse is *NOT* true: you generally *CANNOT* use a newer library on a legacy platform.
4. The good news: if you update ... then you're better able to accommodate *OTHER* changes you might wish to make in the future.